# How to embed js in clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, clojurescript

Say I have some pure js code like maybe:

```
    dimensions = {
        max_height : 800,
        max_width  : 600,
        width  : 800, // this will change
        height : 600, // this will change
        largest_property : function () {
            return this.height > this.width ? "height" : "width";
        },
        read_dimensions : function (img) {
            this.width = img.width;
            this.height = img.height;
            return this;
        },
        scaling_factor : function (original, computed) {
            return computed / original;
        },
        scale_to_fit : function () {
            var x_factor = this.scaling_factor(this.width,  this.max_width),
                y_factor = this.scaling_factor(this.height, this.max_height),

                largest_factor = Math.min(x_factor, y_factor);

            this.width  *= largest_factor;
            this.height *= largest_factor;
        }
    };

dimensions.read_dimensions(img).scale_to_fit();

canvas.width  = dimensions.width;
canvas.height = dimensions.height;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
```

and I want to use this code in clojurescript with `(.drawImage context img 0 0 (.-width dimensions) (.-height dimensions))` without having to rewrite the entire thing in cljs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can take the code above and load it in the page before the `<script>` tag that loads your compiled CLJS code. To load it, you can save it in a different file, eg. `dimensions.js` and load it with a `<script>` tag, or you can embed it in the same HTML document with `<script>` too.

The `dimensions` object will be loaded in the `global` context, so you should be able to access it as `js/dimensions` in your ClojureScript code.